# Sql Server Management Studio pode manipular qualquer banco?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, ssms

Estou fazendo essa pergunta porque acho esse SGBD simplesmente fantástico, então, gostaria de usá-lo com outro banco de dados (não porque eu queira, mas porque a maioria das bases que tenho é no Mysql).

Existe algum adaptador, plugin, ou qualquer recurso que através do Management eu possa manipular um banco no Mysql, Oracle, etc.?

Comment: Uma sugestão => https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/

Comment: hahaha pelo visto a resposta é não né, rsrsrs. Então, vou ver esse produto, porque não aguento mais usar phpmyadmin, preciso de algo decente, as ferramentas da jetbrains são ótimas, mas com certeza essa deve ser paga. Vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: O Access não conta :D ?

Comment: Eu manipulo algumas coisas do oracle no SQL SERVER através de linkedserver. Acredito que deve ser possível para MYSQL

Comment: rray nãooo. Desse aí quero distância!

Comment: Daniel Saraiva, você abre as tabelas de um banco oracle no management studio normalmente? Era algo assim que eu queria.

Comment: Até onde eu sei a Microsoft até agora não permite esse tipo de acesso para plataformas diferentes, o que já vir é [plugin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313125(v=sql.110).aspx) para  migração de dados entre Mysql e o sql server ou a utilização dentro do Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiramente o `Sql Server Management Studio` não é um `SGBD` e sim, de acordo com a Microsoft:

> Ambiente integrado para acessar, configurar, gerenciar, administrar e
>   desenvolver todos os componentes do SQL Server

Como cada `SGBD` tem característica específicas, não é possível utilizar um gerenciador para um específico `SGBD` em outro.

Recomendo a versão gratuita do [EMS SQL Manager](http://www.sqlmanager.net/) que tem um gerenciador para cada `SGBD`, porém mantém uma interface comum.

Comment: ah de fato, me equivoquei, está mais para uma ide mesmo